# How to determine the cross rate in a triangular arbitrage

Tags: arbitrage

I am very confused about what two currencies are to be chosen as the cross rate in a triangular arbitrage.

For example, when the bank quotes are

1. ¥180/£
2. $1.5/£
3. ¥130/$

Does the cross rate have to be ¥120/$?

Couldn't it be $1.38/£?

Can I use any two currencies to calculate the profit?

Comment: It doesn’t matter which rate you treat as the ‘cross rate’ in the same way that there is no one side of a triangle which is more important than the other two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any 2 rates imply the third.

Now what is missing here is that you did not provide actual quotes. A quote is the given of a bid and offer values. If you don’t know each dealer’s bid *and* offer there is no way to assert whether the levels offer an arbitrage opportunity or not. You could see an implied 1.38 level against a fair value of 1.5 however if the bid/offer half-spread is say 0.2 then this spread opportunity would not be a real one as the expected gross profit would be less than transaction costs.